# Errors when compiling the project https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/hog-man

Tags: c++, linux, compilation

I am compiling hog-man under linux GNU C++ using the installation instruction

```
@verbatim
$ svn co http://www.openslam.org/data/svn/hog-man
 $ cd hog-man/trunk/
 $ bash               # if not already running
 $ source setlibpath
 $ ./configure
 $ make
@endverbatim
```

Csparse is installed.

The error is when running the last step:

```
    from hogman2d.cpp:18:
    graph_optimizer_chol.hpp: In member function ‘virtual typename   
    PG::Edge* AISNavigation::CholOptimizer<PG>::addEdge(typename 
    PG::Vertex*, typename PG::Vertex*, const typename 
    PG::TransformationType&, const typename PG::InformationType&)’:
    graph_optimizer_chol.hpp:284:25: error: expected primary-    expression before ‘&&’ token
   if (_guessOnEdges && to->edges().size()==1 && ! to->fixed()){
                     ^
  Failed command was:
   g++ -fPIC -DLINUX -I/home/sophie/hog-man/trunk          
  -D_MY_CAST_=reinterpret_cast -I/home/sophie/hog-man/trunk/aislib -fPIC
  -O3 -Wall -frtti -mmmx -msse3 -c hogman2d.cpp -o hogman2d.o
   in directory  /home/sophie/hog-man/trunk/aislib/graph_optimizer_hogman
  ../../build_tools/Makefile.generic-shared-object:55: recipe for target     'hogman2d.o' failed
 make[2]: *** [hogman2d.o] Error 1
    Compilation in graph_optimizer_hogman failed.
 ../build_tools/Makefile.subdirs:10: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
Compilation in aislib failed.
 build_tools/Makefile.subdirs:10: recipe for target 'all' failed
 make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What is wrong with the expression _guessOnEdges ?

It is declared in GraphOptimizerChol.h the following way:

```
  protected:
  using typename GraphOptimizer<PG>::_guessOnEdges;
```

In GraphOptimizer.h it is defined the following way:

```
  public:
  GraphOptimizer();
  virtual ~GraphOptimizer();

  virtual bool initialize(int rootNode=-1)=0;
  virtual int optimize(int iterations, bool online=false)=0;

  double chi2() const;
  static double chi2(const typename PG::Edge* e);
  static void absChi(double& rotationalError, double&      translationalError,       typename PG::Edge* e_);
  void chiStat(ChiStatMap& emap);
  void sqError(double& are, double& ate, double& mte, double& mre,        const    typename PG::EdgeSet* eset=0) const;

  virtual const bool& verbose() const { return _verbose; }
  virtual bool& verbose() { return _verbose; }
  virtual const bool& visualizeToStdout() const { return     _visualizeToStdout; }
  virtual bool& visualizeToStdout() { return _visualizeToStdout; }
  virtual const bool& guessOnEdges() const { return _guessOnEdges;}
  virtual bool& guessOnEdges() { return _guessOnEdges;}

  virtual void backup();
  virtual void restore();

protected:
  virtual void backupSubset(typename PG::VertexSet& vset);
  virtual void backupSubset(Graph::VertexSet& vset);
  virtual void restoreSubset(typename PG::VertexSet& vset);
  virtual void restoreSubset(Graph::VertexSet& vset);

  bool _verbose;
  bool _visualizeToStdout;
  bool _guessOnEdges;

  using PG::_vertices;
  using PG::_edges;
   };
```

In GraphOptimizer.hpp:

```
 template <typename PG>
 GraphOptimizer<PG>::GraphOptimizer() :
  PG(),
 _verbose(false), _visualizeToStdout(false), _guessOnEdges(false)
   {
   }
```

and in GraphOptimizerChol.cpp:

```
    56: bool initFromObservations = _guessOnEdges;
```

So it is defined, but where is it initialized, is the problem that it is not initialized when this method is executed?

```
     if (_guessOnEdges && to->edges().size()==1 && ! to->fixed()){
      to->transformation=from->transformation*mean;
        }
  return e;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a file.

Comment: Fixed that with the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> using typename GraphOptimizer<PG>::_guessOnEdges;
> ```

When you declare something with `typename`, it means it is a **type**.

You cannot use a type in an expression.

You cannot use `using` on an attribute either.

The solution therefore is twofold:

- remove the `using` statement
- use `this->_guessOnEdges` in your expression

This gives you:

```
if (this->_guessOnEdges && to->edges().size()==1 && ! to->fixed()){
    to->transformation=from->transformation*mean;
}
```

The `this` here is necessary to tell the compiler that `_guessOnEdges` is a dependent symbol and cannot be resolved before instanciation of the template.

Comment: This is a link error, not a compilation error; C++ is finnicky and you must tell the compiler everything twice: where are the include files (so it can compile) and then which library to link with (so it can link). In gcc/clang you use the `-L` argument to list the paths where libraries are and then the `-l` (small L) argument to tell which library to link.

Comment: Is this option also for the make command to include local folders?

Comment: In my case the missing libraries are subfolders from the direction from where I`m running ./configure and make.

Comment: Specified them when executing ./configure using the -l option. They are still not found when running make.